# A mysterious electricity box - what could it be?

Tags: electrical-panel

I am a trustee for a condo building wherein each unit has its own electricity meter. A few owners wanted to install additional appliances in their units, so I conducted a visual inspection of the current electrical configurations and came across this box in the photo.  This box is wired *directly* to one unit's meter.  It stands out from the rest of the electrical boxes (it looks different).

I am looking for feedback here before hiring an electrician (hopefully I will have a better idea of what he is talking about).

Can anyone help me understand what this box is and if it is commonly used?

[image]

Comment: What you're showing is just a box.  What's inside?

Comment: Other then telling what the box is, is there something more you need to know, a problem you need to solve?

Comment: I am just a resident - I can't take the risk to check what's inside.

Comment: There is no problem. I just wish to know why one unit has this box and the others don't. Could it be that there is something inappropriate in installing such a box?

Comment: Just because the box is on "One unit" does not  necessarily mean that it is associated with that unit. We can not tell you anything more about it. You can ask the owner or maintenance person.

Comment: there is no `What could it be?` ... it is definitely an electrical box

Comment: If someone is being really naughty you will find this is connected to the meter for unit X, but is actually feeding unit Y!  That's probably **not** the case, but these days you can't rule it out.

Comment: I just realized that the OP digitally blocked out the unit number on that box cover. At first, I thought it was a piece of white electrical tape because the number had been wrong or something. If the rest of the world knowing that it's `Unit #1` or `Unit #26` wouldn't make a lick of difference - How many apartment/condo/council blocks _are_ there in Cambridge that have a `Unit 1` or `Unit 26` that it could _possibly_ make a difference and help identify this to anyone other than the OP?

Comment: Also, if you really want to know what's going on in there, back the screws out a few turns until the cover is loose, put on some rubber gloves, and gently remove the cover. You'll see some wires and some form of connection between them. Now put the cover back on, screw it down, and call in the electrician to trace down where the circuit comes from and where it goes to so you know what it's for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is a junction box.

It serves as a place where junctions can be made to wires that enter and exit the box.

The junctions, by code, have to be housed in a container to keep them safe but accessible.

We do no know why there is a junction box there other than to provide a code compliant box to house some wire junctions (*splices*).

Answer (score 6):

### Somebody came up short

As others have indicated, this is a junction box.  In this case, it's likely housing a set of splices between the two sets of incoming wires, as a cable came up short during installation, or was damaged at some point so had to be partially replaced. Depending on the gauge of the wires and the locale, it could also very well be a bit undersized (as 4AWG or larger wires need to be spliced in a *pull box* to have sufficient space to work with them), but that's neither here nor there.